# extract value from JSON in sql server

Tags: sql-server

```json
[
    {
        "Levelname": "LGA",
        "levelvalue": "Alimosho"
    },
    {
        "Levelname": "STATE",
        "levelvalue": "LAGOS"
    },
    {
        "Levelname": "SUB ZONE",
        "levelvalue": "LAGOS 2"
    },
    {
        "Levelname": "BRANCH",
        "levelvalue": "LAGOS 2"
    },
    {
        "Levelname": "ZONE",
        "levelvalue": "LAGOS"
    }
]
```

is there a way we can extract this data from JSON and put in the table format like:

```
Lga    STATE     SUB ZONE    BRANCH   ZONE
```

Comment: There's plenty of questions on [so] on how to consume JSON; what didn't you understand about them? What have you tried so far? Why didn't your attempts work?

Comment: `is there a way we can extract this data from JSON`? where is the json? in JavaScript? C# , OR it is hard code in sql?

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi we stored this data in table and want to extract from there.

Comment: see this: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to explode out the array with `OPENJSON` and `JSON_VALUE`, then pivot the values back up into a single row**

You could also use `OPENJSON` again instead of `JSON_VALUE`, and you could place the pivot on the outside if you prefer

```sql
SELECT j.*
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT
            levelvalue = JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.levelvalue'),
            Levelname =  JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.Levelname')
        FROM OPENJSON(t.JsonColumn) j
    ) j
    PIVOT (
      MAX(levelvalue) FOR Levelname IN
        (LGA, STATE, [SUB ZONE], BRANCH, ZONE)
    ) pvt
) j;
```